# gmail to sms from my application

Tags: php, pop3

Does anyone know how can i send a sms messsage when e-mails are arriving in a gmail account?

I know some PHP, C/C++ and C#, and I plan to read the new message using POP3. The problem is that I don't know how can I send a SMS message to a mobile phone. Do I need a SMS server?

can you give me some advices?

Comment: If way2sms works in your country as well, and want to use this application for yourself only( limited person), then you can use way2sms api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to register with and buy credit at some bulk SMS gateway with API. personally, i would recommend: http://www.clickatell.com/
which allows to send SMS via email, HTTP/GET/POST, REST, XML etc.

Comment: do u know other bulk SMS gateways?

Comment: sorry, i don't. i have tried clickatell few times and itwas cheap and reliable. +easy api is a win.

Answer (score 0):

Many cell carriers have the ability to send SMS messages to an email address (ie yourphonenumber@telus.com).  If you're sending to a *specific* mobile phone (for keeping an eye on your website, say), this would be something to look into, because it's free and simple.  For the general case of sending an SMS to *any* mobile phone, that's somewhat more complicated.  You can either hook into an SMS gateway (such as clickatell, as dusoft mentions), or you can attach a GSM modem to your PC and send commands through it.

Comment: or as someone has been able to do - reuse free SMS via google calendar - just schedule the email to the next minute and gcalendar will send you the sms (if you have verified your cell phone number in it)

Comment: how can i use modem to send sms in c# or any other languae??